# VSCode's debugging mode always stop at first line

Tags: python, debugging, visual-studio-code

I am using vscode for python development. I sometimes use debug running mode, and vscode always stop at first line even if there are no breakpoints. I attached a screenshot of this phenomenon.
It's a little annoying and I want to skip this. Are there any ways to skip this?

**My Env**

- Code Runner 0.6.5
- MagicPython 1.0.3
- Python 0.5.5
- Python for VSCode

[image]

Comment: Take look to that post **["vscode python debuging stop on first import and when exceptions exist even if not breackpoint"](https://github.com/DonJayamanne/pythonVSCode/issues/519)** where you will have details on how to change settings.

Comment: Thank you! I can do it by fixing stopEntry to false in launch.json.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

The launch.json file has the setting `"stopOnEntry":true`. Change this to `false` to prevent this.

The docs for this can be found https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging#_stoponentry

Comment: Is there a way I can set it to be false on default? I hate having to reset this on every new configuration I run

Comment: What I do is use the `Ctrl` + `H` keyboard shortcut to replace all the `"stopOnEntry": true` entries with `"stopOnEntry": false`. I don't think there is a way to set it by default.

Comment: somehow this only works on start but not on restart (when "restart": true)

Comment: Thanks. Why on earth would people want StopOnEntry to be enabled by default?

Answer (score 1):

There are many of them make sure to make all of them false (Stop on Entry)

Answer (score -1):

For my embedded project it was `"runToMain": false`