# vscode node debugger with custom webpack build

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, visual-studio-code

I have a JS web app that has a client and server bundle, both built using webpack's node api.

Running my project in dev mode goes through these steps:

1. Run two webpack builds, resulting in two output files.
2. Server bundle is output to dist/server/index.js
3. Spawn child node process using the dist/server/index.js path
4. Watch folder for changes. On change, kill the old child process and re-run steps 1-3

I want to add node server debugging using vscode.

So far, I've added the following flags during step 3, when I launch a new child process.

```
['--inspect=9222', '--no-lazy', '--inspect-brk']
```

My launch.json file in vscode looks like this

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Attach to dev server",
            "type": "node",
            "request": "attach",
            "protocol": "inspector",
            "address": "localhost",
            "port": 9222,
            "restart": true,
            "trace": true,
            "stopOnEntry": true
        }
    ]
}
```

When I start the server and run the debugger, things mostly work.

**However, I'd love to fix the following two things:**

1. Even with `"stopOnEntry": true`, the debugger will not pick up any breakpoints, unless I include `"--inspect-brk"` when launching my child process. This is annoying, because if I'm not running the debugger, the process will hang and will not continue execution. With this flag included, when I run the debugger, the built `dist/server/index.js` file will open in my editor with a breakpoint on line 1. If I hit continue, all future debugging works.
2. I'm generating sourcemaps using webpack's ["inline-source-map"](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/devtool/) option. This puts the "original source" in the built file. However, it's the source after babel transformation, making debugging the code a little annoying. `E.g. _myFunction.default instead of myFunction`. Does vscode have a way to correctly map the built .js file to the pre-built source code in my project? I saw the `remoteRoot` and `localRoot` options, but could not get them to work (and am unsure if these are the correct options).

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Update VS Code 1.47+:

With the [new JavaScript debugger](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-js-debug) in [VS Code 1.47](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_47#_new-javascript-debugger) and later versions, child processes [are automatically debugged](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-js-debug#debug-child-process-and-workers) in Node.js - just set breakpoints where needed.

Example `launch.json` (with TypeScript source to illustrate the sourcemap approach):

```
{
  "type": "pwa-node",
  "request": "launch",
  "name": "Launch Program",
  "skipFiles": ["<node_internals>/**"],
  "program": "${workspaceFolder}/main.ts", // use .ts source
  "outFiles": ["${workspaceFolder}/dist/**/*.js"], // search here for sourcemaps 
}
```

Example `main.ts`:

```
const { spawn } = require("child_process");
const args = [path.resolve("./child.js")];
const proc = spawn(process.execPath, args, { stdio: "inherit" });
```

See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63442436/what-is-the-pwa-node-type-launch-configuration-on-vscode) for an explanation of `pwa-node`.

### VS Code debug options

**`program`**: specifies main source file to be debugged. You can directly reference the `.ts` source file - VS Code will [search the workspace for sourcemaps](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/nodejs-debugging#_source-maps) or consult `outFiles`.

**`outFiles`**:  tell VS Code to explicitely search for sourcemaps in these glob locations.

**`sourceMaps`**: if VS code shall look for sourcemaps; [defaults to `true`](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/nodejs-debugging#_source-maps), so no need to set.

**`stopOnEntry`**: [breaks immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41407583/vscodes-debugging-mode-always-stop-at-first-line) when program launches - same, as a breakpoint on first line.  <sup>1</sup>

**`nolazy`**: ensures that breakpoints [are validated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21534565/what-does-the-node-js-nolazy-flag-mean) before the code is run and don't "jump". Per default, VS Code [sets this flag *automatically*](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/nodejs-debugging#_breakpoint-hit-counts), so it can be left out.

**`remoteRoot`** / **`localRoot`**: are for [remote debugging](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/nodejs-debugging#_remote-debugging) and are not directly related to generating sourcemaps (see OP question).

**`autoAttachChildProcesses`**: was used to automatically attach to child processed launched in debug mode; no need to set it with new debugger.

### Node debug options

**`--inspect`**: starts the program [in debug mode](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/debugging-getting-started/#command-line-options) without waiting for the debugger to be attached.
**`--inspect-brk`**: same as `--inspect`, but [waits for the debugger](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/nodejs-debugging#_attaching-to-nodejs) to attach [before starting](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/75253#issuecomment-500792543).

You can set one of these to enable debug mode for a program started on the command-line. Note: VS Code now can also [auto-attach](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/nodejs-debugging#_auto-attach-feature) from  [integrated terminal](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-js-debug#debug-nodejs-processes-in-the-terminal) without these flags given.

### Generate sourcemaps with Webpack

For webpack, you can [generate sourcemaps](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/devtool/) with `inline-source-map` or `source-map` <sup>2</sup>.

```
// inside webpack.config.js
devtool: "inline-source-map",
```

If `babel-loader` is used, sourcemaps should be considered and merged automatically by webpack with above config entry. For TypeScript, see the [Webpack docs](https://webpack.js.org/guides/typescript/).

---

### (Old) Debug child legacy solution

If that does not work in older versions, pass a conditional `DEBUG` environmental variable for `--inspect`/`--inspect-brk` together with `autoAttachChildProcesses`:

```
const runner = spawn(process.execPath,
  [...(process.env.DEBUG === "true" ? ["--inspect-brk"] : []), ...args],
);
```

```
// inside launch.json configuration
"env": {
  "DEBUG": "true"
},
```

---

<sup>1</sup>  <sub>Despite this [developer comment](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/65697#issuecomment-456338043), `stopOnEnty` has *not* been propagated to child processes for me - even with `autoAttachChildProcesses` and child processed  started with `--inspect`.</sub>

<sup>2</sup> <sub>These options provide best compatibility from my experience.</sub>

Comment: Thanks for the writeup, certainly helpful. As far as the sourcemaps working correctly,  I think that they are being mapped correctly. I needed to change my "import from" to "require('')" to see things in a completely ES5 format. As far as autoAttachChildProcess, I cannot get it to work. I can get the listener to start, and can even see the child process as recognized by vscode (If i add the -inspect node flag to the child processes), but the breakpoints always show up as not verified (code never stops). I'm also unable to get anything to work without having the initial "inspect-brk."

Comment: Here's an image of what the debug window looks like in vscode https://i.imgur.com/iWbWxMx.png

Comment: Thanks for the followup and the sample repo! good to know about inspect-brk and child processes. I think in this case, having a process.env variable control what flag the child process runs with is the best option.